# Grpc for .NET - Why is Client Streaming so much slower than Server Streaming?

Tags: .net, grpc

When I implement gRPC for .NET server streaming, performance is strong-- upwards of 40,000 460-byte messages per second with a single client.  When I implement client streaming, performance is poor-- no more than 500 messages per second.

The client streaming pattern requires that each message is flushed from the buffer.

Why the stark difference? Is it about HTTP/2 and the request stream?

I've implemented my client-server using the original .proto file method and in a whole other implementation, the code-first methods (no meaningful difference in performance between the two).  I cloned the Grpc.Net.Client repo and benchmarked various aspects of it.  I removed the buffer flush and this made little difference in performance.  The bottleneck is at the async write to a stream, which apparently ends up in a Http2 client stream deep inside the runtime.

I wrote a gRPC client and server and implemented the client streaming pattern using HttpListener, HttpClient, and Http/1.1.  My throughput was well over 13,000 messages per second on the request stream, far better than gRPC .NET and HTTP/2.